# List categories associated with post in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'm using Jekyll as my blogging platform and it's great. Right now I have the following code that I'm trying to tweak in my index.html page so that it only displays the categories associated with each post.

For example let's say I have the following posts:

```
| Post Name    | Category      | 
|--------------|---------------|
| Post1        | Travel Dining | 
| Post2        | Projects      |
```

When the post list displays I want to get something like:
Post1, 6/7/15, Category: Travel Dining

Here's what I have for code:
    Filed In: 
        `{% for category in site.categories %}
        <a href="/{{ category | first | slugize }}/">{{ category | first }}</a>
        {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is not clear but maybe this code can do the job.

```
<ul>
{% for p in site.posts %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{p.url}}">{{p.title}}</a> -
        {{ p.date | date: "%a, %b %d, %y" }}
            {% unless p.categories == empty %}
                -
                {% for cat in p.categories %}
                    <h1>{{ cat }}</h1>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endunless %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Only problem is it concatanetes the categories for some reason. For example, if I have two categories such as "life travel" it displays them like "lifetravel." Any way to fix this?

Comment: How would I link it? This is what I have currently but it's not working. `{% unless p.categories == empty %}
                  {% for categories in post.categories %}
                      <a href="/{{ categories | first }}">{{ categories }}</a>
                  {% endfor %}
              {% endunless %}`

Comment: You're asking a new answer in the comments. First agree my answer if you think it's ok. Second ask a new question about linking post categories to something.

Comment: See the new thread: [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215381/how-to-link-post-categories-in-jekyll)